# Конфиг apache2 ошибка после редактирования

Tags: ubuntu, flask, apache2, wsgi

Имею flask питон приложение, запускаю его на удаленном сервере (ubuntu server, работающий в virtual box, подключение к нему выполняю по ssh). Поставил в ubuntu server веб-сервер apache2, изменил его конфиг, чтобы запустать flask приложение, apache2 не стартует, с ошибкой: `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` `systemctl status apache2.service` выдает:

```
 apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-09-12 18:57:27 UTC; 5min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 3627 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver apachectl[3639]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 19 of /etc/apache2/sites>
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver apachectl[3639]: order not allowed in <VirtualHost> context
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver apachectl[3627]: Action 'start' failed.
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver apachectl[3627]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, statu>
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 12 18:57:27 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Содержимое файла `000-default.conf`:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                              000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        WSGIDaemonProcess flex-server-web threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flex-server-web/app.wsgi


            WSGIProcessGroup flex-server-web
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Настройку apache2 делал по описанию [отсюда](https://pythobyte.com/deploy-flask-app-on-vps-f5574039/)

Comment: содержимое файла error.log (из директории /var/log/apache2)
```
[Sun Sep 12 15:00:59.057436 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1694:tid 140706840751168] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 12 15:00:59.057584 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1694:tid 140706840751168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Sep 12 15:01:47.842447 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1694:tid 140706840751168] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

```

Comment: ```
[Sun Sep 12 15:01:48.042079 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2448:tid 140022165859392] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 12 15:01:48.042193 2021] [core:notice] [pid 2448:tid 140022165859392] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Sep 12 18:51:31.375950 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2448:tid 140022165859392] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: А, ну вот ошибка `order not allowed in <VirtualHost> context`. Собственно, её текст прекрасно говорит сам за себя